# Of several bootstrap popovers on page, I need one scrollable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have many bootstrap popovers on a page, but the first one, triggered by an  with an id, I need to make scrollable (and have included js to make it stay open to scroll), which is trivial enough in css, but I haven't been able to make only that specific one scroll, the others do also...:

```
.popover-content {
max-height: 100px;
overflow-y: auto;
}


$(document).ready(function() {

$("#scrollpop").popover({ trigger: "manual" , html: true})
  .on("mouseenter", function () {
      var _this = this;
      $(this).popover("show");
      $(".popover").on("mouseleave", function () {
          setTimeout(function () {
          if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
              $(_this).popover("hide");
          }
      }, 100);
      });
  }).on("mouseleave", function () {
      var _this = this;
      setTimeout(function () {
          if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
              $(_this).popover("hide");
          }
      }, 100);
  });

});
<a href="#" rel="popover" id="scrollpop">Text Here</a>
```

Is there a way to do this, without being to invasive and work for IE8/IE9 browsers?

Thank you!

Comment: Couldn't you target your CSS specifically at that element like `#scrollpop .popover-content {}`? If not, can you provide a http://JSFiddle.net

Comment: ugh, you would think so, ala #scrollpop .popover-content {
max-height: 100px;
overflow-y: auto;
}

but I got nowhere with that... the .popover-content part is bootstrap, so it's not really associated with that container..

Comment: I totally disagree with you. the `.popover()` function creates the popover inside/relative to the `#scrollpop` element, so you should be able to reference it relative to each other. Please provide a http://JSFiddle.net

Comment: Ok man, go forth and conquer: http://jsfiddle.net/crunchfactory/h39GY/

UPDATE - was in a hurry, this one: http://jsfiddle.net/crunchfactory/h39GY/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just had a look locally, it looks like Bootstrap adds popover elements **after** the element in which you target your popover to be triggered on, e.g.

```
$('#test').popover();

<span id="test">Hello world!</span>
<!-- popover gets generated here -->
```

So, you can use the [adjacent](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/adjacent-sibling-selector-css-selector/) [sibling](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/) [selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) in CSS to target the fact that the popover container element is a directly following sibling of the original element. You then use a `.popover-content` selector after that to target the child element of the popover container (your example now):

```
/* target .popover-content elements that are children of .popover 
   elements that occur directly after the #scrollpop element       */

#scrollpop + .popover .popover-content {
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

**Edit:** [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h39GY/3/).